# Pandas set_index not setting index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to set the index of a df, except it doesn't work:

```
def save_to_csv(timestamps, values, lower, upper, query):
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': timestamps, f'Q50-{format_filename(query)}': values})
df.set_index('Time')
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
print(df.tail())
df.to_csv(f"predictions/pred-Q50-{format_filename(query)}.csv")
```

and here is the output:

```
                       Time  query_value
149007  2023-05-15T15:55:00                                           0.301318                               
149008  2023-05-15T15:56:00                                           0.301318                               
149009  2023-05-15T15:57:00                                           0.301318                               
149010  2023-05-15T15:58:00                                           0.301318                               
149011  2023-05-15T15:59:00                                           0.301318
```

I still have the original index and not the **Time** column set as index.
Any fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when saving to CSV, putting a `index=False` fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is designed for chaining. This means that most operations return a modified version of the dataframe. Rather than reassigning at each line, the chaining format is used. Your call of set_index is returning the dataframe you want, but you aren't reassigning it to df.

This is how it would look with chaining.

```
def save_to_csv(timestamps, values, lower, upper, query):
    df = (pd.DataFrame({'Time': timestamps, f'Q50-{format_filename(query)}':values})
          .set_index('Time')
          .assign(Time=lamdba x: x['Time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
          )

    print(df.tail())
    df.to_csv(f"predictions/pred-Q50-{format_filename(query)}.csv")
```